# Переместить метку Яндекс.Карты 2.1

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Приветствую. Есть отличный [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_properties) по изменению координат.

Как его дополнить, что бы при первом клике появлялся маркер (отметка) и при клике в другое место карты он переставлялся?

Заранее прошу подробно, т.к. новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap,
  myPlacemark;

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [57.5262, 38.3061], // Углич
    zoom: 13
  });

  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark();

  myMap.events.add('click', function(e) {
    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(e.get('coords')); // устанавливаем метке координаты, высчитанные из положения клика
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark); // ставим метку на карту
  });



}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! то что нужно: myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(e.get('coords'));
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

Comment: Галочку поставил, а плюс ещё не дают ставить.

Comment: @Cheg хорошее решение (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_T благодарю)